# How can I systemwide check if a keyboard shortcut is in use or has been registered?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, command-line

How can I query OS X to know if an application has registered a shortcut?

I could inspect every app I have or that is running at least with KeyCue and go through the Keyboard Shortcuts section of System Preferences, but there must be some other method using the shell.

Comment: I think it depends on which version of osx you are using.  I am going to post osx 1.8.5 and once you specify which version of osx you are running I can update the answer.

Comment: I think you should also change the title of your question to mention it is keyboard shortcuts you are asking about, when I came across your question I thought you were talking about file shortcuts or ln's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```

Will do it for you. Then you can edit the individual keys from there.

The details are extracted from:
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57337941-263/tackling-keyboard-shortcut-woes-in-os-x/

You can modify the above file as per:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4850

However note the file is binary and you cannot use a text editor, you have to use the command `defaults`, or the command `PlistBuddy`.  `defaults` can be used if you know the individual keys you want to modify.  `PlistBuddy` is more user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the plist reference. This way I found some useful documentation about the plist self, http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785.

Comment: If that is the answer to your question, you should put it in answer format and tick it as self answer. NP by the way.

Comment: I know this is and old thread... but, does anyone know how to decipher this keyboard plist file?

Comment: @FlakDiNenno did you ever find out?

Comment: @montrealist no, unf I didn't